# How to determine latency and packet loss with access point I am connected to in wireless network?

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, wifi

Hi I am a c programmer but I've never programmed for networks before. I would like to write a program in c or c++ for Linux that will be able to verify the latency of access point and packet loss.
I was thinking that maybe ICMP request/respond (ping) would be not too bad idea? 
If above idea is good how this could be accomplished?
What libraries i will have to use to accomplish it? 
I was using nmap software for scanning before (one type of scanning it supports is ping scanning) and I think nmap is using **libpcap** library.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using ping?

Comment: That's true I could just use ping command but the idea is to implement it in c.

Comment: Ping is already implemented in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BWPing** is a tool to measure bandwidth and response times between two hosts using Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo request/echo reply mechanism. Its source code is what I was looking for - http://sourceforge.net/projects/bwping/files/ .

Answer (score 1):

For linux, you could make a program to parse the `/proc/net/wireless` file. Let the kernel get the information for you.
`iwconfig` gets information from there (http://linux.die.net/man/8/iwconfig)

Comment: thanks Andre that's interesting but the idea is to use c programming language to transmit/receive the packets and calculate the latency and packet loss based on these packets.